# What is the name for casting with the letter after a number?

Tags: c#

So I was looking at the [C# Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) and I didn't see this in the example list though I know it works.

What is it called when you cast by putting a letter after the number.

```
var longValue = 100L;
```

According to the documentation it's not covered under implicit or explicit casting.

Is there a name for it?

I'm not asking how to do it. I am asking specifically what is it called. Please don't mark it as a duplicate unless you link something that has a name in it.

Comment: yes duplicate, and see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/how-do-i-tell-c-what-kind-of-literal-number-i-want/

Comment: It's not on that documentation page because it's not a cast or conversion.

Comment: It is not a cast. It's not an `int` that is converted to a `long`. It's a `long`.

Comment: The name is in the dupe title btw. C# short/long/int **literal format**,

Comment: @AnthonyRussell It's a `long` literal.  That's the name for it.

Comment: Numeric suffix: http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: C# doesn't infer a 32bit int from `100L` any more than it infers one from `"100"`.  Different value types have different literal notations, that's all.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell THe `L` tells C# that you want a `long`.  And since you use `var` the compiler implicitly types `longValue` to `long`.  If you had used `int longValue = 100L`, _then_ there would be a conversion attempt to `int`.

Comment: This includes no casting.  In c# it is part of the integer literal within the spec. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: And a number without quotes will be considered a 32bit int if you don't specify that it's a string.  What's your point?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell It looks to me you answered your own question: you say 100L to tell C# you mean to say `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: I love that he asks for the correct terminology then gets the question closed as duplicate/downvoted because a question about literals already exists. It clearly isn't the same question and I'm fairly sure asking basic things isn't disallowed.

Comment: @KellyGendron that's life... Their couple downvotes ain't hurting my feelings lol.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Haahaa - SO downvotes are serious business! Have been on this site for a while and I guess the over-eagerness to close new questions is a huge pet peeve of mine. Duplicates especially as people don't take the time to understand the question - just react if they see similar keywords. I understand the frustration with dupes it has gone too far in the other directions and makes the site less useful as a resource. I don't ask q's often but frequently search and find a relevant question closed as dupe (with no answers) and linked to a subtly non-relevant question - is frustrating.

Comment: I actually prefer people post duplicate questions as long as they are marked duplicate and linked to the answers. The reason being is that there will be more pages with new was of asking the same questions indexed on Google linked to the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specify literal type.
See for [integer literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.